# Is there any way to get minecraft java edition on mac m1chip for free

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I really need to know if there is any way to get **minecraft java edition on mac m1chip** laptop for **free**

Answer (score 4):

You can download the client to get a free trial.

Other than that, no. While you could easily look up "mac minecraft free" or something, **please don't resort to piracy.** There are a number of reasons not to, but if you're thought is "they have a lot of money already, they don't need more" - while that's already the wrong mindset, if that's not enough then by pirating games you are supporting piracy which leads to more piracy in other games, not to mention that any shady stuff off of the internet can easily be bundled with malware and adware.

**No,** buy it or use the free trial.